# Synchronized method implementation and wrong behavior in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

```
class prab implements Runnable {
    public synchronized void toTest() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception" + e);
            }
            System.out.println("I am from Prab " + i
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        toTest();
    }

}

public class threadClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("---");
        Thread t = new Thread(new prab());
        Thread c = new Thread(new prab());
        t.start();
        t.setName("I am T");
        c.start();
        c.setName("I am c");
        System.out.println("From Main thread");
    }
}
```

Out Put: ---

```
From Main thread
I am from Prab 0I am T
I am from Prab 0I am c
I am from Prab 1I am c
I am from Prab 1I am T
I am from Prab 2I am c
I am from Prab 2I am T
I am from Prab 3I am T
I am from Prab 3I am c
I am from Prab 4I am T
I am from Prab 4I am c
I am from Prab 5I am T
I am from Prab 5I am c
I am from Prab 6I am T
I am from Prab 6I am c
I am from Prab 7I am T
I am from Prab 7I am c
I am from Prab 8I am c
I am from Prab 8I am T
I am from Prab 9I am T
I am from Prab 9I am c
```

Expected O/P: first thread T should complete then thread c.

Answer (score 3):

You have `synchronized` on different objects, since adding `synchronized` on method signature will lock the current instance. And you have created two object.

Synchronized should be on common object, then only you can see the expected output. Use one `prab` object for both Threads, then see the output

```
prab p = new prab();
Thread t = new Thread(p);
Thread c = new Thread(p);
```

Comment: and `void toTest() {synchronized(p)` instead of `synchronized void toTest()`

Answer (score 0):

`synchronized` will block on a common object or method.  try using static to share or just create one `prab` obect

Answer (score 0):

`synchronize` synchronizes on object instances, not types.